# How to make axios post to a database in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to do a simple login system with mysql+axios+express+react.

Connections with my database are going well, but these two specific posts get errors like "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and UNCAUGHT IN_PROMISE.

error message

> POST localhost/3001/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError

my database:
[image]

my codes:
`

```
app.post("/api/register",(req,res) => {

    const email = email
    const senha = senha

    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `alunos` (`email`,`senha`) VALUES (?,?);"
    db.query(sqlInsert,[email,senha],(err,result)=>{
        res.send(result);
    });
});

app.post("/api/login",(req,res) => {

const email = email
const senha = senha

db.query("SELECT * FROM  `alunos` WHERE email = ? AND senha = ?;",[email,senha],
    (err,result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({err:err});
        }
        
        if(result.length>0){
            res.send(result);
        }else{
            res.send({message: "COMBINAÇÃO ERRADA."});
        }
    }
)});

const register = () => {
    Axios.post('https://localhost/3001/api/register',{
        email: "testmail",
        senha: "testpassword",
    }).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    });
}

const login = () => {

    Axios.post('https://localhost/3001/api/login',{
        email: "testmail",
        senha: "testpassword",
    }).then((response)=>{
        if(response.data.message){
            setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
        }else{
            setLoginStatus(response.data[0])
        }
    });
}`
```

Whats going wrong? I really think it's a problem with my mysql statement because other mysql statements work right.

Comment: please don't save passwords in plain text even when it is for  a school project. And which errors do you get exactly

Comment: this looks loke a netwrk error and not a code problem, have you check the error log

Comment: @nbk it's not a network problem because other posts work pretty right. I really think it's a problem with the way I write the statements 'insert.....' but I just cant help it

Comment: have you checked that db has a valid connection?

Comment: @nbk how to do that?

Comment: you debug like any other error,

Comment: yes it does have a valid connection. if I call another post right before any of these, the first one works and then login doesnt work.

Comment: connection refused says that the connection wasn't establish so db can't have a valid connection.

Answer (score 0):

it worked. I was using '' instead of ""